# does nvcc always work as gcc when there is no CUDA elements in the code?

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-12.04, nvcc

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have installed CUDA 5.5. I understand that without any CUDA/GPGPU elements in the code, nvcc behaves as a C/C++ compiler -- more like gcc, however is there any exception to this rule ? if not, then can I use nvcc as gcc for non-CUDA C/C++ codes ?

Comment: Seems weird that you would not just use gcc directly.

Comment: I wish to see the limits of nvcc, it is not an issue of utility, rather a comparison of gcc and nvcc !

Comment: I think there is something on this in the CUDA manual. I would expect problems with command-line arguments...

Comment: Can you refer me to that link ?

Comment: By Googling you will find it; http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide. Look at the section on Compilation with NVCC, it may contain some information about this.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look !

Comment: You can pass the gcc options that are not supported by nvcc using `-Xcompiler OPTIONS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nvcc doesn't behave like a C/C++ compiler for host code. What it does is the following:

1. separate device from host code into two separate files
2. compile device code (with nvcc, cudafe, ptxas)
3. invoke gcc for host code

If no device code exists, nothing is done in steps 1) and 2). So nvcc is actually no compiler, it is a compiler driver which invokes the right compilers for every part in the right order. To answer your question, if you use nvcc to compile host code only, you still use gcc.

Comment: You might also want to read the [nvcc user's guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't accept options to suppress warnings ( -W*)